# problems when a cat eats cucumber leaves?

Tags: cats, diet, plants

In my head this question is kinda awkward.

this year we started planting some vegetables on the balcony. (for your information it's strawberries, tomato, cucumber, bell pepper, hot pepper, lemon balm, mint)

So our cat is usually pleased when he gets some herbs (afaik helps digestion) and usually he tries to get the balm. Recently he discovered the big leaves of our cucumbers and since then he is acting kinda odd.

Whenever we are near the balcony door, he would start complaining and showing that he wants to go there. When we give in, he goes straight for the cucumber leaves and we don't know why he behaves this way.

What could this behaviour of his mean? Is there anything in that plant that might help or harm him?

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tomato and pepper are in the Nightshade family and toxic, so I'd worry about those, but he can probably tell.

I believe cucumber is safe.

Many cats enjoy nibbling selected plants. Adding fiber to the diet may help them deal with hairballs, and it may help clean their teeth, so unless you are worried about damage to the plant this is harmless at worst. You could try redirecting his attention by planting some grass for him -- pet stores often sell grass seeds selected for the purpose -- or perhaps even some catnip, but he may consider the cuke interesting even with his own crops available.

Normal behavior. I had a cat who liked broccoli, though that may have been because she saw me eating it.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, i know the nightshades could cause problems but he ignores them and when he could get near them he is not alone.